# Python + Sqlite3 Передать данные из одной БД в другую

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Нужно осуществить копирование данных из одной базы данных в другую. В изначальной существует 5 столбцов с данными, в другой так же 5 столбцов, но пустых. Может как-то нужно взятые данные записать в массив и передать их?
Код:

```
    cur = base_admin.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM offers WHERE title == ?', (callback_query.data.replace('accept_offer ', '',)))
    read = cur.fetchall()
    base = sq.connect('historyBook.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO book VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (read,))
    base.commit()
```

Выводит следующую ошибку:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: Сколько полей в первом запросе забираете, столько знаков вопроса во втором ставите

Comment: Исправил код в вопросе. При таком коде, выдает ошибку. До этого был экспериментальный код.

Comment: в read лежит не 5 колонок. там целая таблица.

Comment: Как тогда передать в INSERT не целую таблицу, а по частям, чтобы он записал все на свои места?

Comment: read укажите как параметр. Как есть. Это уже кортеж кортежей. Не надо скобок и запятых. Ну мил человек, ну остановите код в отладчике, ну посмотрите что у вас в переменной. Ну не удобно писать ответы с кодом с телефона. Если никто до вечера не сподобится, напишу код в ответе